# Flask can read a POST datum but not another

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, post

So I'm trying to pass some data from my front-end to the back-end. It is the user's nickname and the location of the user. But while I can read and print out the nickname in flask, I always get *None* when I want to read the location value in the backend. I'm not really sure why this is happening, since I can actually print the *location* value in the javascript console before passing it to the backend and everything is allright. I would really appreaciate any help :)

This is my relevant code:
**JS**

```
$(document).on("submit", "#get_nickname", function(e)
    {
    var coords = {};
    //Get location
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(loc){
            var latlng = loc.coords.latitude + "," + loc.coords.longitude;
            String(latlng);

            latlngContainer = latlng;
            coords.latlng = latlngContainer;
        });
    }
    console.log(coords);

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/add_address",
      data: {
          nickname:$("#nickname").val(),
          location: coords
      },
      success: function()
      {
        set_address_cookie(31);
        session_memory();
        add_address_toggle();
      }
   })
});
```

**PYTHON**

```
@app.route("/add_address", methods=['POST'])
def add_address():

    nickname = request.form.get("nickname")
    location = request.form.get("location")
    print(f"Hi {nickname}, you are here {location}")
    return "", 201
```

Here are some pictures:

[my chrome console log with everything allright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoQEm.png)

[the error shown on flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWBN2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location is being dropped because it's an object. Try to send the data as json however you will have to modify your flask app to accept it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/add_address",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        nickname:$("#nickname").val(),
        location: coords
    }),
    success: function()
    {
        set_address_cookie(31);
        session_memory();
        add_address_toggle();
    }

});
```

**EDITS:**

I just noticed `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback is asynchronous meaning it executes later when the ajax already happened. You have to wait for it to finish executing before posting. I am not sure what environment you're working from but I re-wrote your JS try it and see if it works for you.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#get_nickname", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    function addAddress(data){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/add_address",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function()
            {
                set_address_cookie(31);
                session_memory();
                add_address_toggle();
            }
        });
    }

    var data = { nickname: $("#nickname").val() }
    var coords = {};

    //Get location
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(loc){
            var latlng = loc.coords.latitude + "," + loc.coords.longitude;
            String(latlng);

            latlngContainer = latlng;
            coords.latlng = latlngContainer;
            data.coords = coords;
            addAddress(data); //submit with coords
        }, function(){
            addAddress(data); //submit without coords when failed to get coords
        });
    } else addAddress(data); //submit without coords when not supported

});
```

Comment: I don't jnow if I wrote it wrong, but it still returns none :/

Comment: I have edited the answer. hopefully it'll help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Excuse my poor experience with js but it worked!